# How often does this achievement happen in basketball?

Tags: basketball, nba

We have 5 categories in basketball which we take into account when triple-double or quadruple-double is achieved. They are: points, rebounds, assists, steals, and blocked shots.

The achievement of quadruple-double is extremely rare, triple-double is not so rare, and I have defined the achievement that splits rebounds into offensive ones and defensive ones and I do not know how often such an achievement happens?

Now, to define it:

> Let us call an achievement in basketball a *jumper´s triple-double* if the following two conditions are fulfilled:
>
> 1) The player has a double digit number of offensive rebounds and a double digit number of defensive rebounds.
>
> 2) The player has a double digit number of two out of the remaining four categories.

So, for example, if someone has 19 points and 10 assists and 23 rebounds and if 8 rebounds are offensive and 15 defensive than he did not achieve a *jumper´s triple-double* but if 11 rebounds are offensive and 12 defensive than he did achieve a *jumper´s triple-double*.

Now, two questions:

> 1) How often does the achievement of *jumper´s triple-double* happen (for instance, how many times we can expect it in one professional basketball season (you can take NBA as an example if you want))?
>
> 2) Can you give some documented examples of basketball players that achieved *jumper´s triple-double*?

---

**NOTE**: The term *`jumper's triple-double`* is **NOT** an official term for any basketball statistic and has been made up to indicate a particular statistic just for the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How often should you expect it? Never. [Only 24 times since 1983 has a player recorded a triple double with 20+ rebounds](http://bkref.com/tiny/AXazj), which is the absolute minimum required to even look at the offensive/defensive breakdown.

Since the 1983-1984 season, which is as far back as Basketball Reference has rebounding stats, only one player has achieved your "jumper's triple double". [That player was Shaquille O'Neal.](http://bkref.com/tiny/B53bw) On November 20, 1993, in his second season in the league, he had 18 defensive rebounds, 10 offensive rebounds, 24 points, and 15 blocks.

[It was a pretty good game.](http://ballislife.com/shaq-triple-double-24-points-28-rebounds-and-15-blocks-1993/)

Comment: Well thank you! I thought that maybe Wilt Chamberlain did it among the first ones, and I still do not know if he did it, but those were the times when statistics was not at today´s level so I do not know how to know if he did it first?